# Charles Proxy and Windows Phone when using HTTP Queries (need SSL certificate)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, charles-proxy

I am trying to use Charles proxy to see if my API call are correct and i am having issues seeing my https calls, has anyone ever installed Charles proxy and used https on Windows Phone 8.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after looking and trying different things, here is the full solution:

You phone and windows machine need to be on the same network (of course)

*On your Windows device:*

On open cmd -> ipconfig get the IP of your windows device.

*On your Phone:*

In your Wi-Fi parameters, activate Proxy, set the IP of your windows device on your phone and the port on which the proxy is listening on ( for me it was 8890)

Then in Internet explorer go to: **http://www.charlesproxy.com/getssl**  and install the certificate

*On your Windows device:*

**In Charles under **SSL proxy setting** add the location to which you want to proxy, for me it was api.Blabla.com I did not put a port number.**

In Charles proxy you should not be able to see https traffic. =)